# What do the markings on Obi-Wan's ship mean?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, revenge-of-the-sith, symbols, object-identification

In *Revenge of the Sith* we catch a glimpse of some strange markings on the side of Obi-Wan's Jedi Starfighter. Do we know what they mean?

[image]

Comment: _why_ the downvote? I'm always happy to use feedback to improve my questions.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but some people dv things that seem really obvious, and kill tally marks are a pretty common thing on fighter planes, especially in WW2.

Comment: Really I had no idea

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to *Star Wars: Revenge of the Sith Incredible Cross-Sections*, a DK Publishing reference book published in 2005<sup>1</sup>, they are kill markings; although the diagram in the book shows Anakin's fighter, not Obi-Wan's, the markings are the same:

[image]

> Kill markings, equivalent to tri-fighter squadron

That seems like a strange thing for a Jedi to be tracking, but there you go<sup>2</sup>.

Out of universe, this is a reference to a very real practice of fighter pilots, especially in World War 2; a Google Image search for "plane kill tally" will show you hundreds of historical examples.

[image]

Since Lucas rather famously [based his starfighter scenes on WW2-style dogfights](http://www.starwars.com/news/from-world-war-to-star-wars-dogfights), it's reasonable to assume that this was an intentional reference.

---

<sup>1</sup>Since this was a reference book published before the Great Disneyfication, the status of this information under Disney Canon is questionable.

<sup>2</sup> Of course, it occurs to me that this isn't the first time we've seen Jedi do this; in "Landing at Point Rain", an episode of *The Clone Wars*, we see Anakin, Ahsoka, and even Ki-Adi Mundi comparing their kill counts. So maybe it's not as odd as all that

Comment: Well, it's still in the movie and the marks clearly resemble the droid attack fighters. Don't see any canon issue with that, unless they remaster the "old" episodes.

Comment: *That seems like a strange thing for a Jedi to be tracking* - I'd hazard a guess that Obi-Wan didn't do them personally, it would most likely be the maintenance crew (without being asked, since it is traditional).  I suppose if he'd ordered them not to they'd obey, but it probably didn't matter enough to him to be worth making an issue of it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I also remembered that we've seen Jedi tracking kills before; not Obi-Wan, but maybe he got off his high horse about it in the intervening period

Comment: It'd make sense to me if they only tracked droid kills, since they don't seem to value droids as life.

Comment: @CreationEdge True, but then "violence is not the Jedi way." Ah well, if it's good enough for Ki-Adi

Comment: Remember they're counting droid kills in this case.  Obi-wan and Anakin often partook in friendly competition.